# How do I change the material of an object with Script in Unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript, materials

I was making a game with Unity and I want to change an object's material using UnityScript when the player collects 5 collectables that I made. The collectables get stored in an int variable called Score.

Comment: Do you want to change the material or a property from the assigned material ?

Comment: The material.Like the texture thing on top of an game object.Those files stored as .mat .

Comment: in C#: gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = new_texture; the "Javascript" code should be similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change a Material in Unity you have to retrieve it first.

If your GameObject uses a [Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html) it means that it uses a [Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html).

You can retrieve your object renderer using the internal variable `renderer` or get it using the `GetComponent` function. On the renderer object you will find a [material](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) property containing the active `Material`.

For example:

```
MeshRenderer my_renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
if ( my_renderer != null )
{
   Material my_material = my_renderer.material;
}
```

If you want to change the current material, you can use the same access. For example:

```
my_renderer.material = other_material;
```

I suggest to make `other_material` a `public Material` variable of your game object. However if you want to load it at runtime you should have a look at [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Material[] mainMat;

Renderer rend;

public static int index;

public static int i;

public void Start()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    rend.enabled = true;
//  rend.sharedMaterial = mainMat [0];
}

public void changeMat()
{
    if (i == 0) {
        rend.sharedMaterial = mainMat [0];
        i++;
    } 
    else if (i == 1) 
    {
        rend.sharedMaterial = mainMat [1];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you repeat yourself at the bottom there, retyping the same code except for a number, instead of just using `i` as the array index and  writing this code just once?